# Ajax call works great, but non-ajax call renders wrong in browser. What did I miss?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, ajax

In a non-ajax call, the ordering of divs inside other divs gets messed up and the page renders wrong.  When the same call is done via Ajax, the page renders perfectly.

So I have this search form on my master page:

```
 <form action="<%=Url.Action("Search") %>" method="post" id="search1" class="search-form">
            Search:
            <%=Html.TextBox("SearchBox1", null)%>
            <input  type="submit" value="Go" />
 </form>

 .....

 <div id="search-results">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server" />
 </div>
```

I also have this javascript to submit the search form using Ajax:

```
$('.search-form').ajaxSubmit(GetSearchAjaxFormOptions());
```

and

```
function GetSearchAjaxFormOptions() {
    return { target: '#search-results',
        data: GetSearchData(),
        success: RunAfterAjaxSubmit()
    };
}
```

when the form is sumbitted via Ajax, everything renders beautifully. When I turn Ajax off and submit the form, The rendered html is messed up. Like there was a misplaced element or something in there.  The divs on the page do not end up inside the right divs.  I looked at and diffed and ... all sorts of thing to find the difference, and I cant see any thing that would cause this.

My controller method is:

```
public ActionResult Search()
{

  if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
  {
    return View("SearchResultsPartial", sm);
  }
  else
  {
    return View("Index", sm);
  }
```

}

My Index.aspx is:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>

<asp:Content ID="indexTitle" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    Home Page
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="indexContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
          Html.RenderPartial("SearchResultsPartial");
</asp:Content>
```

and my SearchResultsPartial.ascx is:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<MyWebSite.Models.SearchModel>" %>
<% 
            int count = Model.searchResults.Count();
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                Response.Write(Model.searchResults.ElementAt(i));
            }
%>
```

My model has:

```
public IEnumerable<String> searchResults;
```

So an important thing is that the search engine returns to the model a collection of strings. Each string is an html of a search result.  This was generated by using linq to xml and is really the result of the XElement.ToString() call.

And my master page has:

```
<div id="search-results" class="yui-u"> 
      <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server" />
</div>
```

Any help in finding what to do to fix this is most appreciated.  I have ran out of things to look at myself.

Many thanks!

Comment: `Response.Write`? *Srsly?* And you should return `PartialView()` to AJAX requests. :) Go through one of the excellent ASP.NET MVC tutorials on the official web site, it will really help you.

Comment: @bzlm, the result of Model.searchResults.ElementAt(i) is a string that is held in the search index.  It is a piece of xhtml that has been created using linq to xml and at the end turned into a string by XElement.ToString.  If I want to generate this complex xhtml from data on the fly, the search results will be too slow for users. Now I stick this xhtml inside my document by using Response.Write.  How do you recommend I do it instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay,

The linq to xml engine does not understand that div tags are not self closing and for empty div tags it creates `<div />`. Somehow the browsers handle this just fine when doing an ajax call and mess it up when doing a non-ajax call. This behavior is standard among all browsers.

So the solution was to put a blank space in the empty div tags generated by linq to xml. So we end up with `<div> </div>` and not `<div/>`.

```
new XElement("div", new XAttribute("class", "my-class"), "");
```

And then everything works out perfectly.

Comment: Here is an interesting corollary: if the resulting xml is saved in sql server as an xml data type, the empty div tags <div></div> will be saved as <div/> which means that the problem persists when saved to the db.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace

```
<asp:Content ID="indexContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
          Html.RenderPartial("SearchResultsPartial");
</asp:Content>
```

with

```
<asp:Content ID="indexContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
 <div id="search-results">
          Html.RenderPartial("SearchResultsPartial");
 </div>
</asp:Content>
```

in Index.aspx.

Comment: Thanks Max. I edited the question to add the relevant part f the master page:
<div id="search-results" class="yui-u"> 
      <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server" />
</div>

Comment: I still took it out of the master page and put it in index, like you suggested, and unfortunately, nothing changed.